# How do I set session variables from javascript vales in a script

Tags: javascript, php, function

Ok, so here is the ordeal. I have a  class in a .php file with a javascript function that is being called in an onclick event. Everything there works fine and dandy, however I need to execute a php function within the script and set a few session variables before I can do that. This is the php I need inserted into the javascript function:

```
    $_SESSION["AccountUsername"] = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    $_SESSION["Email"] = document.getElementById("tEmaili").value;
    $_SESSION["Password"] = document.getElementById("Password").value;

    addaccount();
```

I have the .php file with the php function set to

```
require_once(thefile.php);
```

at the beginning of the file.
Than you to anyone that can offer insight or a solution. I'm fairly new to this, so feel free to give extra pointers.

Comment: PHP is a server side language and JavaScript is client side, they don't work "together" as such, you have to get them to talk to each other. Try [googling PHP Form handling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+forms&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB744GB744&oq=php+forms&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5912j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=php+form+handling).

Comment: You may best want to study yourself into AJAX ... You must send those javascript variables from the clientside to the server side to have PHP create SESSION variables out of it.

Comment: Are you trying to insert PHP into JS or vice versa?

Comment: Please restate the question.

Comment: The question is quite clear, The code I have listed is within a script, in a .php file.

Comment: I've changed the way I test if fields are full to now using php forms, so I no longer need to use php in js at all, and can just use php.